# How do I implement events that shows the next page after it is clicked?

Tags: reactjs, events, addeventlistener

I made a component called NewName where it has a button with text "New". I want the page to go to the second component that I made called "ProfileInformation".

This is the "NewName.js" component that has the new button in it

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class NewName extends Component {


render() {
    return ( 
        <div>
            <button>New</button>
        </div>
    )
}
}


export default NewName
```

This is the component that I want to go to when the new button is clicked. It has other components. It is the "ProfileInformation.js" component.

```
import React from 'react'
import UserDetail from "./UserDetail"
import ProfilePicture from "./ProfilePicture"
import UserName from "./UserName"

class ProfileInformation extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <ProfilePicture />
                <UserName />
                <UserDetail />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default ProfileInformation
```

I want the ProfileInformation component to render in the screen after the user hits the new button.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use react-router to navigate between pages. here is official page: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/guides/quick-start